# Memory leak with C# and flex form application

Tags: c#, winforms, apache-flex, memory-leaks

I am experiencing Flex form black out issue in my project [Desktop App C# & Flex Forms] after opening multiple child windows with flex forms. While investigating this issue using memory profilier I found this is happening due to memory leaks. While closing child windows memory is not getting released completely even after waiting for few mins.

To narrow down the issue I have created a very simple light weight desktop app which launches child winform with blank Flex from the parent form button click. While closing child window I am properly disposing objects (axshockwaveFlashPlayer and proxy) and handles then also I see the memory keeps increasing for each child window and remain constant even after closing all the child windows. I have also tried to dispose objects at flex end while closing child window but no luck.

As per the DebugDiag profiler analysis report, \Flash32_22_0_0_209.ocx is responsible for 138.44 Mbytes with 95% leak probability.

However, I don’t find any option to release memory while closing a child form.

Can anyone suggest what else can be done to resolve this issue.

I am using Flash player version 22.0.0.209. Appreciate your help here.

**As per VMMAP Tool memory analysis**
*If i open 10 child windows memory increase from 400 to 700MB and when i close all the child windows it comes down to only 600 MB and it reamins constant.
Please note committed memory always comes down to where it started. 
Only concern is with "Private Data" which never comes down. I am not sure what is Private Data and what we can do from code to release that memory.*

Please find below code for your reference

```
 //Child form code start
 public Childwindow1(string flexURLPath)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Closing += Childwindow1_Closing;

    host = new WindowsFormsHost();
    player = new FlashAxControl();

    _flexURL = flexURLPath;

    host.Child = player;
    this.grdChildWindow1.Children.Add(host);
    player.LoadMovie(_flexURL);   //call load movie method of user control      to load 

   }


 //While closing disposing objects
 void Childwindow1_Closing(object sender,    System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
    host.Dispose();
    player.Dispose();
    host = null;
    player = null;

}
 //child form code ends here
```

//User Control code

```
  //User Control - LoadMovie Method
public void LoadMovie(string strPath)
 {
    axShockwaveFlash.LoadMovie(0, strPath);

 }


 //user control - Disposing object - AXshockwave and calling GC

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
  {
    if (disposing && (components != null))
    {
        components.Dispose();
        components = null;
    }
    if(disposing && (axShockwaveFlash != null))
    {
        Proxy.ExternalInterfaceCall -= ProxyExternalInterfaceCall;
        Proxy.Dispose();
        Proxy = null;
        axShockwaveFlash.Dispose();
        axShockwaveFlash = null;
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
  }
```

Comment: How you show the form?  If you show it as modal (form.ShowDialog()), to dispose it, you MUST call Dispose() manually or use the "using" statement. Closing of modal window insufficiently for dispose it.

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev Thanks. it's not a modal (form.show()).

Comment: I see similar issue reported on adobe forum and accepted as a known issue of Flash player version 10.  Any thought whether that is not fully resolved with Flash player 22.0 as well?? Thanks.  https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2194243